# Default S3 bucket in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does each sagemaker session has its own default bucket or all sessions share same default bucket? Also if latter is true, then do all notebook instances have same default bucket? Is there a single default bucket for one aws account(per account id)?